# Expression within condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

This is a follow up question:

I want to aggregate the average of a collection only for documents with type 'buy'.
So the problem is how to get the if condition around the sum expression and same for totalBuyAmount. Check the comments in the code :)

These are example documents:

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("653c4c017800342a3bedb82e"),
    type: 'buy',
    item: 555,
    amount: 1,
    priceEach: 100000
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("653c4c017800342a3bedb830"),
    type: 'buy',
    item: 384,
    amount: 2,
    priceEach: 70000
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("653c4c017800342a3bedb831"),
    type: 'buy',
    item: 384,
    amount: 1,
    priceEach: 50000
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("653c4c017800342a3bedb831"),
    type: 'sell',
    item: 384,
    amount: -1,
    priceEach: 50000
  }
]
```

I need to totalBuyPrice only if type === 'buy'

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$item",
      totalBuyPrice: {
        $sum: { // Only if type === 'buy'
          $multiply: [
            "$priceEach",
            "$amount"
          ]
        }
      },
      totalBuyAmount: // $sum $amount if type === 'buy'
      totalAmount: {
        $sum: "$amount"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      avg: {
        $divide: [
          "totalBuyPrice",
          "totalBuyAmount"
        ]
      },
      amount: "$totalAmount"
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `$cond` operator to perform calculations based on the condition.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$item",
      totalBuyPrice: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$type",
                "buy"
              ]
            },
            {
              $multiply: [
                "$priceEach",
                "$amount"
              ]
            },
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      totalBuyAmount: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$type",
                "buy"
              ]
            },
            "$amount",
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      totalAmount: {
        $sum: "$amount"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      avg: {
        $divide: [
          "$totalBuyPrice",
          "$totalBuyAmount"
        ]
      },
      amount: "$totalAmount"
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oxJ52wGFsKG)

Comment: Works perfect, I was very close to the solution :)